# Python Networking does not compile

Tags: transcrypt

I cannot use the python socket module
It says:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Coding Projects\chatserver>Transcrypt import_test.py -b
Transcrypt (TM) Python to JavaScript Small Sane Subset Transpiler Version 3.6.4
Copyright (C) Geatec Engineering. License: Apache 2.0

Error in program import_test.py, module _socket, line 49:
        Attempt to load module: _socket
        Can't find any of:
                C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Coding Projects/chatserver/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Coding Projects/chatserver/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/lib/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/lib/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/Scripts/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/Scripts/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/python36.zip/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/python36.zip/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/DLLs/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/DLLs/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/lib/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/lib/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/lib/site-packages/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js
                c:/program files (x86)/python36-32/lib/site-packages/__javascript__/_socket.mod.js

Aborted
```

---

Python File:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print("HI")
        try:
            import socket
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error: " + str(ex))
```

Answer (score 0):

With repect to importing modules like `sockets` note the following points:

- Transcrypt is a compiler rather than an interpreter. This means that imports are done compile time, to be able to compile also the imported modules and include them in the generated code. Since they are compile-time, they cannot be runtime conditional, generate runtime exceptions etc..
- If you need compile time condional imports use __pragma__ ('ifdef', ... which works compile time.
  You'll need websockets rather than the CPython sockets module, which is probably written in C, hence cannot run in a browser. Since you can use any JS library or API function, you can use e.g. HTML5 web sockets or any JS socket lib. Just use it exactly the same as from JavaScript.
- In general, for Transcrypt, use JS libraries, since they're most suited to do their work in the browser.
  See also: http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/what_why.html#the-ecosystem-different-batteries

[EDIT]

Further clarification:

You should use the Python websockets package only on the server side, so not with Trancrypt.

What I meant is that on the client you should use JavaScript websockets functionality as decribed a.o. at the following locations:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/

Since these are JavaScript facilities, they won't require sys or things like that.
So take care NOT to import websockets in your Transcrypt client code, since this will give you the Python package, rather than the JavaScript facility that is available natively.